# how to use checkboxes to change values for TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a form with 2 checkboxes and 3 buttons. When Button3 is clicked the program checks if the checkbox1 is selected, if it is selected the value for textbox 1 changes to "Hello". If the checkbox2 is selected the value changes to "please help".

```
using System;   
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;   
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;   
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "a";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "b";
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            If (checkBox1.Checked = true ) ;
            { 
                textBox1.Text += ("hello ");
            }

            If(checkBox2.Checked = true);
            {
                textBox1.Text += ("hello ");
            }

            txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic";
            txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 18);
            txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
            // Add the textbox control to the form's control collection               
            this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
        }

        private void bindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds great, so what's the problem? Please be specific, as per the [FAQ]. Also, the code that you've posted doesn't compile. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;` in all if statement lines and do as below

```
if (checkBox1.Checked) 
{ 
    textBox1.Text = "hello ";
}

if(checkBox2.Checked)
{
    textBox1.Text = "please help";
}
```

if you do something like `yourTextBox.Text +="something"` that will append `something` to current textbox text.

if you need to replace or entirely change the textbox text you can do as `yourTextBox.Text ="something"` ( without `+`)

And you have dynamic control but can't find the declaration of it

```
txtRun = new TextBox();
```

change that to

```
TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
```

Comment: Edited to fix `if` and remove the `= true` which will btw assign true and go into the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

If statement in button3_Click handler is wrong
It must be like

```
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true ) //or if (checkBox1.Checked)
    { 
        textBox1.Text += ("Hello ");
    }

    if(checkBox2.Checked == true) //or if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        textBox1.Text += ("please help ");
    }
```

remove the semicolons at the end of the "if".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's the question, but you have one problem in the if sentence, and note, also you have problem in this case the program run only ";" sentence if the result of if is true... remove the `;`

```
        If (checkBox1.Checked == true ) 
        { 
            textBox1.Text += ("hello ");
        }

        If(checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            textBox1.Text += ("hello ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will accomplish this

> When Button3 is clicked the program checks if the checkbox1 is selected, if it is selected the value for textbox 1 changes to "Hello". If the checkbox2 is selected the value changes to "please help".

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked)textBox1.Text = ("Hello");
        if(checkBox2.Checked)textBox1.Text = ("Please Help");
    }
```

For some reason I have a feeling your question is incomplete and I was only able to answer exactly what you asked, if there is anything else you are trying to accomplish please provide me with more details and I will be glad to extend my answer.

Also as a side note when you dynamically create that textbox in your original code(which might I add is not addressed at all in your question) it will continually create an infinite number of TextBoxes underneath each other since every time you hit the button it creates another in the same spot.